# Error in importing image through URL and adding it on the panel

Tags: java, swing, url, jlabel, imageicon

```
public class Interface 
{ 

    private static JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem;
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JTable table;

 public Interface()
 {

   JFrame f= new JFrame("Content Provider Generator");
   f.setFont(new Font("Aharoni", Font.BOLD, 12));
   f.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
   f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);


   //JToolbar//

   JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
      f.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.EAST);

  //MenuButton//

      JButton button = new JButton();
      button.setIcon(new ImageIcon
        (Interface.class.getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/menu.gif")));
      toolBar.add(button);   //added to JToolbar

      JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
      addPopup(button, popupMenu);

      //popupmenu
      mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Table");
```

**//WHEN POPUP Menu(Table) is  CLICKED//**************************************

```
 mntmNewMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            //This method will be called whenever you click the button.
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              JLabel label = new JLabel();
            try {
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL
                     ("file:/C:/Users/Ashad/JunoWorkspace/FYP1/table.png")));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   

                panel.add(label); 

            }
        });
```

****************************//*******************************************

```
      popupMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem);


       //Image Import on click to panel

       mntmNewMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, 
                                                              InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
       mntmNewMenuItem.setIcon(newImageIcon(Interface.class.getResource
            ("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/menu.gif")));


      //////////////////MenuBar/////////////////////////   
      JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
      f.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);



      //Menus added/initialized in MENUBAR//


      JMenu mnNewMenu = new JMenu("File");
      menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);

      JMenuItem mntmNew = new JMenuItem("New");  //mntmNew
      mntmNew.setIcon(new   ImageIcon(Interface.class.getResource
                              ("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/file.gif")));
          mnNewMenu.add(mntmNew);

      JMenuItem mntmSaveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As...");
      mntmSaveAs.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Interface.class.getResource
                               ("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/floppy.gif")));
      mnNewMenu.add(mntmSaveAs);

      JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
      mntmSave.setIcon(new ImageIcon
      (Interface.class.getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/metal/icons/ocean/floppy.gif")));
      mnNewMenu.add(mntmSave);

      //M_Exit
      JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");


      //When exit of the menuBar  is clicked//
      mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
      {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
      });


      mnNewMenu.add(mntmExit);



      JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
      menuBar.add(mnEdit);

      JMenuItem mntmUndo = new JMenuItem("Undo");
      mnEdit.add(mntmUndo);

      JMenuItem mntmRedo = new JMenuItem("Redo");
      mnEdit.add(mntmRedo);

      JMenuItem mntmCut = new JMenuItem("Cut");
      mnEdit.add(mntmCut);

      JMenuItem mntmCopy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
      mnEdit.add(mntmCopy);

      JMenuItem mntmDelete = new JMenuItem("Delete");
      mnEdit.add(mntmDelete);

      JMenu mnSearch = new JMenu("Search");
      menuBar.add(mnSearch);

      JMenuItem mntmSearch = new JMenuItem("Search");
      mnSearch.add(mntmSearch);

      JMenuItem mntmFile = new JMenuItem("File");
      mnSearch.add(mntmFile);

      JMenuItem mntmJava = new JMenuItem("Java");
      mnSearch.add(mntmJava);

      JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
      mnHelp.setFont(UIManager.getFont("OptionPane.messageFont"));
      menuBar.add(mnHelp);

      JMenuItem mntmWelcome = new JMenuItem("Welcome");
      mnHelp.add(mntmWelcome);

      JMenuItem mntmHelpContents = new JMenuItem("Help Contents");
      mnHelp.add(mntmHelpContents);

      //Panel (Drawing board)//  panel
      panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



      f.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      Label label = new Label();
      label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      panel.add(label);

      table = new JTable();


      table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
      table.setVisible(false);
      table.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
      table.setAutoscrolls(false);
      table.setAlignmentY(2.0f);
      panel.add(table);
      table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {null},
            {null},
            {null},
            {null},
        },
        new String[] {
            "Table"
        }
      ));
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(145);
      f.setVisible(true);   //set visible  
      f.setSize(600,400);    //set size
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


 }

 public void addtoPanel(Component c)
 {
   panel.add(c);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)

{
    new Interface();


}

private static void addPopup(Component component, final JPopupMenu popup) {
    component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                showMenu(e);
            }
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                showMenu(e);
            }
        }
        private void showMenu(MouseEvent e) {
            popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    });
}

}
```

Look at the part of code that is in between stars !! that part is not working  properly. as its not adding any image to panel on click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my interpretation of the question is correct, you can use the constructor of `ImageIcon` that accepts `URL`, ie:

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(
        "http://duke.kenai.com/iconSized/duke.gif")));
```

Also note, that after adding controls to a container, the container needs to be revalidated, ie call `validate();` and `repaint();`.

***EDIT:***

For local files there is a constructor that takes a file name, ie:

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/User/Desktop/1.png"));
```

You could also use URL if needed:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/1.png");
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(file.toURI().toURL()));
```

You can also use back slashes, just escape them, ie: `C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\1.png`.

Another way to create URL to a local file:

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL("file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/1.png")));
```

***EDIT***

Try this simple example to display your image:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DisplayImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Image image;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/1.png"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to load image");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C:\Users\Ashad\JunoWorkspace\FYP1\table.png   This is the URL it is not working ... please correct me

Comment: @AshadChaudhary `label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Ashad/JunoWorkspace/FYP1/table.png"));` should be ok if image exists. It could be the slash issue, make sure you use forward-slash.

Comment: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
 at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at build.Interface$1.actionPerformed(Interface.java:63)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 
 
  !!ERROR!!

Comment: What code did you use to get this error? See last edit regarding local files and URL.

Comment: label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL("C:/Users/Ashad/JunoWorkspace/FYP1/table.png")));                                        panel.add(label);

Comment: This is an incorrect way to allocate URL to a local file. Either use `File.toURI` or try: `label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL("file:/C:/Users/Ashad/JunoWorkspace/FYP1/table.png")));`

Comment: can you please send me your email ID i badly need help ?

Comment: P.s . nothing happened to the panel no change by last changes that u told me

Comment: You have to call `validate(); repaint();` after `panel.add(label);`. The problem is that you will probably need to repack you frame as well.

Comment: or menupopup.validate(); and menupopup.repaint();

Comment: how to make actionListener for a JLabel ?? i want like if we click this picture it will show another form..   actionListener for Jlabel i guess is different because its giving error